# popup not load the jsp scripts while loading second time in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jsp

i had created a web page which consist jsp pages with parent and child format. while i click to load child jsp page as popup using ShowmodalDialog function of javascript. the popup page runs the JSP scripts in the client side page whenever it calls in all the browser except IE. in IE the jsp scripts runs first time only and in next time it doesn't runs the JSP scripts. Thanks in advance. Please do the needful. sorry for my bad english.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%> 
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import = "Precision.Biometric.PB400.App_Code.*"%>
<%@ page import = "Precision.Biometric.PB400.Presenter.*"%>
<%@ page import = "Precision.Biometric.PB400.View.*"%>
<%@ page import = "org.joda.time.format.*" %>
<%@ page import = "org.joda.time.*" %>
<%@ page import = "java.text.*" %>
<%@ page import = "java.util.*" %>
<html>
<base target="_self" />
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery/JQuery.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery/jquery-ui-1.10.3/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    if (screen.width == 1024)
    {
        document.write('<link href="CSS/design1024.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
    }
    else
    {
        document.write('<link href="CSS/design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
    }
</script>   

<script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery/jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery-ui.js">
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/HolidayDetails/HolidayDetails.js"></script>
<title>Precision Attendance</title>
</head>
<body onload="onload()">
<%!
int admin = 1;
%>
<%
try
{
    HttpSession sess =  request.getSession(true);
    if(sess.getAttribute("UserID")!=null)
    { 
        admin = Integer.parseInt(sess.getAttribute("UserID").toString());
    }
    else
    {
        /*RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp");
        if(rd != null)
        rd.forward(request, response);*/      
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
 %>
<%
HttpSession sess1 =  request.getSession(true);
String Error ="";
if(sess1.getAttribute("Error")!=null)
{
            Error =sess1.getAttribute("Error").toString();
}
%>
<%! 
boolean restrictedGroup = false;
boolean Group1 = false;
boolean Group2 = false;
boolean Group3 = false;
boolean Group4 = false;
boolean Group5 = false;
boolean Group6 = false;
%>
<%
try
{
    HttpSession sess =  request.getSession(true);
    HolidayDetailsPresenter hdPresenter = new HolidayDetailsPresenter();
    PredefieneddataCollectionList pdfList = new PredefieneddataCollectionList();
    pdfList = hdPresenter.GetPredefinedDetails(admin);

    if(pdfList.size()>0)
    {
        if(pdfList.get(0).CompanyName.size()>0)
        {
            pageContext.setAttribute("companyList", pdfList.get(0).CompanyName);
        }
    }
    if(sess.getAttribute("CompanyID") != null)
    {
        System.out.println("comapnid"+sess.getAttribute("CompanyID").toString());
        if(pdfList.size()>0)
        {
            if(pdfList.get(0).CompID.size()>0)
            {
                 int index = pdfList.get(0).CompID.indexOf(Integer.parseInt(sess.getAttribute("CompanyID").toString()));
                 pageContext.setAttribute("selcmbCompany", pdfList.get(0).CompanyName.get(index));
            }
        }
    }
    if(sess.getAttribute("HolidayGroup") != null)
    {
        String[] grp = sess.getAttribute("HolidayGroup").toString().split(":");
        if(grp.length>0)
        {
            restrictedGroup = true;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<grp.length; i++)
        {
            if(grp[i].equals("1"))
            {
                Group1 = true;
            }
            else if(grp[i].equals("2"))
            {
                Group2 = true;
            }
            else if(grp[i].equals("3"))
            {
                Group3 = true; 
            }
            else if(grp[i].equals("4"))
            {
                Group4 = true;
            }
            else if(grp[i].equals("5"))
            {
                Group5 = true;
            }
            else if(grp[i].equals("6"))
            {
                Group6 = true;
            }
        }       
    }

}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
%>
<%!
public String sbtvalue(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    HttpSession sess =  request.getSession(true);
    String temp = "0";
    if(sess.getAttribute("rtnvalue")!=null)
    {
        return (String)sess.getAttribute("rtnvalue");
    }
    return temp;
}
%>
<%!
public String getHolidayID(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    HttpSession sess =  request.getSession(true);
    String tempHolidayID = "-1";
    if(sess.getAttribute("HolidayID") != null)
    {
        tempHolidayID = sess.getAttribute("HolidayID").toString();
    }
    return tempHolidayID;
}
%>
<%!
public String getHolidayName(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    HttpSession sess =  request.getSession(true);
    String tempHolidayName = "";
    if(sess.getAttribute("HolidayName") != null)
    {
        tempHolidayName = sess.getAttribute("HolidayName").toString();
    }
    return tempHolidayName;
}
public String getHolidayDate(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    HttpSession sess =  request.getSession(true);
    String tempHolidayDate = "";
    if(sess.getAttribute("HolidayDate") != null)
    {
        tempHolidayDate = sess.getAttribute("HolidayDate").toString();
    }
    return tempHolidayDate;
}
public String getHolidayCompany(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    HttpSession sess =  request.getSession(true);
    String tempCompany = "";
    if(sess.getAttribute("CompanyID") != null)
    {
        tempCompany = sess.getAttribute("CompanyID").toString();
    }
    return tempCompany;
}
public String getHolidayDescription(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    HttpSession sess =  request.getSession(true);
    String tempHolidayDescp = "";
    if(sess.getAttribute("Description") != null)
    {
        tempHolidayDescp = sess.getAttribute("Description").toString();
    }
    return tempHolidayDescp;
}
%>
<form name="holidayDetails" id="holidayDetails" method="post" action="HolidayDetails">
<div class="PageHeaderTitle">   <h2 align="center"> Holiday Details</h2></div>
<div style="vertical-align: super">
<table class="popupTable" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="10px">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td><label for="lblHolidayName" id="lblHolidayName" >Holiday Name</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="holidayName" class="textBox" id="holidayName" onkeydown="return isAlphaNumeric(event.keyCode);" maxlength="100" value="<%=getHolidayName(request)%>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><label for="lblCompanyName" id="lblCompanyName" >Company Name</label></td><td><select name="cmbCompany" id="cmbCompany" class="comboBox">
<c:forEach items="${companyList}" var="cmpList" >
        <option value="${cmpList}" ${cmpList == selcmbCompany ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>${cmpList}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="lblDate" id="lblDate" >Date</label>   </td>
<td><input type="text" name="dtpholidayDate" id="dtpholidayDate" value="<%=getHolidayDate(request)%>" class="textBox"/></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="lblDescription" id="lblDescription" rows="4" cols="50">Description</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="holidayDescription" id="holidayDescription" value="<%=getHolidayDescription(request)%>" class="textBox" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id ="chckRestrictedGroup" name="chckRestrictedGroup" onclick="disableRestrictedGroup()" <%=restrictedGroup?"checked" : "" %>/>  <label for="lblRestrictedGroup" id="lblRestrictedGroup">Restricted Group</label></td>
<td><select name="lstGroup" id="lstGroup" multiple="multiple" class="comboBox" style="height: 80px">
<option <%=Group1?"selected" : "" %>>Group1</option>
<option <%=Group2?"selected" : "" %>>Group2</option>
<option <%=Group3?"selected" : "" %>>Group3</option>
<option <%=Group4?"selected" : "" %>>Group4</option>
<option <%=Group5?"selected" : "" %>>Group5</option>
<option <%=Group6?"selected" : "" %>>Group6</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><div class="ButtonDiv">
<input type="button" name="btnSave" value="Save" onclick="save()" class="buttonStyle" />&nbsp;
<input type="button" name="btnCancel" value="Cancel" onclick="cancel()" class="buttonStyle" />
</div><input type="hidden" id="hdtxtcheck" name="hdtxtcheck" />
<input type="hidden" id="txthidden" name="txthidden" value="<%=sbtvalue(request)%>"/>
<input type="hidden" id= "txtHolidayID" name = "txtHolidayID" value="<%=getHolidayID(request)%>"/>
<input type="hidden" id= "selCompany" name = "selCompany"/>
<input type="hidden" id= "selGroup" name = "selGroup"/>
<input type="hidden" id="hdtxtError" name="hdtxtError" value="<%=Error%>"/>
</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the javascript to call the page in popup

```
function Add()
{
    try
    {           
        holidayList.hdtxtcheck.value="1";
        var answer = window.showModalDialog("HolidayDetails.jsp","precision","dialogWidth:600px; dialogHeight:500px; center:yes");
        holidayList.submit();
    }
    catch(ErrorMessage)
    {
        alert(ErrorMessage);
    }
    return;     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the cache control headers to tell the browser not to cache the page.

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

It seems like others browser by default retrieve the page again on new request unless you tell them to cache, whereas IE has a tendency to cache by default until you tell it not to.